# Turning a column in to a string

Tags: mysql

I want to make 1 query but it is hit by performance issues due to this warning:

> Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''

See I have this query:

```
SELECT b.ID,  
(SELECT SUM(case when ABBO != '0' then 1 else 0 end)
       FROM OCCASIONS where HBODBED = b.ID) as BEOORDELINGEN,
(SELECT SUM(case when ABBO != '0' then ABBO else 0 end)
       FROM OCCASIONS where HBODBED = b.ID) as TOTAAL
FROM BEDRIJVEN b WHERE ACTIVE = '1' AND GROEP = '0'
ORDER BY APERC DESC LIMIT 0, 50;
```

But HBODBED is a varchar(30) and b.ID is a  bigint(20)
so lets run a single query:

```
SELECT SUM(case when ABBO != '0' then ABBO else 0 end) as total,
       SUM(case when ABBO != '0' then 1 else 0 end) AS BEOORDELINGEN
    FROM OCCASIONS where HBODBED = 59;
```

still gets warnings and execution time is 0.6498 seconds not bad but if you run 2 of those 50 times it adds up

But if I add string markers to 59 like this: '59' it removes the warnings and the execution time is reduced to 0.0078 seconds so my question is:

How can I add those string markers to b.ID in the top query?

Comment: One simple improvement is to compare integers as integers, not strings, and as an aside, note that MySQL supports `SUM(ABBO != 0)` syntax

Comment: @Strawberry thnx for the copare hint i added it to my query saved me some execution time and the reason I'm summing ABBO's is becouse it gives my users a score but the column name is a bit off

Comment: _But HBODBED is a varchar(30) and b.ID is a bigint(20)_... and then you have this `where HBODBED = b.ID`. There is a double conversion involved, both operands are converted to floats. This explains the warning and slow performance.

Comment: @SalmanA yes that is the whole issue but I can't change the datatypes of both columns so my question is if I could correct it in the query and make it run faster by doing so

Comment: Garbage In, Garbage Out, unfortunately. :-(

Comment: What is the datatype of `ABBO`?

Comment: `HBODBED = 59` is slow because it cannot use an index because the `VARCHAR` must be converted to numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this join condition:

```
WHERE HBODBED = b.ID
```

where you are comparing varchar(30) with a bigint. MySQL will convert both operands to floating-point numbers and compare them. Besides conversion, the comparison of floating point numbers itself is an expensive operation.

The correct solution is to convert the datatype of columns so that they match. If that is not an option, you can try converting *one* of the operands:

```
WHERE HBODBED = CAST(b.ID AS char)
WHERE CAST(HBODBED AS signed) = b.ID
```

Now only one of the operands is converted. When converting to bigint you will still get "truncated incorrect INTEGER value" warning for values that did not convert to float earlier.

Comment: If I replace the where with your code I get a sql syntax error

Comment: I see. `CAST` does not accept varchar or bigint. Try `WHERE HBODBED = CONCAT(b.ID, '')` and `WHERE CAST(HBODBED AS SIGNED) = b.ID` (signed-ness must match that of ID column)